# Extract summary effect from object of class "summary.coxph"

Tags: r

I have object of class "summary.coxph"

```
Fixed-effects meta-analysis
Call: meta.summaries(d = A[[i]]$hr, se = A[[i]]$se, method = c("fixed"), 
    names = A[[i]]$metabolite, conf.level = 0.95)
Summary effect=1.09   95% CI (1.05, 1.13)
Estimated heterogeneity variance: 0  p= 0.398
```

I need to extract `Summary effect`, `95%CI` and `p`. But all my attempts failed. Could you please help me.

My data looks like this:

```
$             :List of 14
  ..$ effects        : num [1:3] 1.07 1.07 1.14
  ..$ stderrs        : num [1:3] 0.0298 0.0421 0.0436
  ..$ summary        : num 1.09
  ..$ se.summary     : num 0.0213
  ..$ test           : num [1:2] 51.2 0
  ..$ het            : num [1:3] 1.841 2 0.398
  ..$ call           : language meta.summaries(d = A[[i]]$hr, se = A[[i]]$se, method = c("fixed"), names = A[[i]]$metabolite, conf.level = 0.95)
  ..$ names          : chr [1:3] "XXL.VLDL.TG" "XXL.VLDL.TG" "XXL.VLDL.TG"
  ..$ tau2           : num 0
  ..$ variance.method: chr "fixed"
  ..$ weights        : num [1:3] 1124 563 525
  ..$ weight.method  : chr "fixed"
  ..$ conf.level     : num 0.95
  ..$ logscale       : logi FALSE
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "meta.summaries"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "summary.coxph"
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: look at the last lines of `rmeta::print.meta.summaries`

Answer (score 0):

Following @rawr's comment, you will find:

Given a `summary.coxph` object `x`, use `x$het[3]` for the p-value,
`x$summary` for the summary effect, and
`x$summary + qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975)) * x$se.summary` for the 95% CI.